# The difference between the boundary maps of 2 tetrahedrons

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, cw-complexes

Here is the first figure on pg.105 in Allen Hatcher:

[image]

But I am not sure why the negative sign before $[v_0, v_2, v_3]$ and $[v_0, v_1, v_2]$ in the boundary map. Could someone explain this to me please?

Also, how the boundary map of the previous figure differ from the boundary map of the following figure(on pg.104 of Allen Hatcher), could someone explain this to me please?

> [image]

As far as I understand, the previous figure has 4 zero simplices, 6 one simplices and 3 two simplices, am I correct?

Comment: This is just the definition of the boundary map. On your second picture you also have a tetrahedron but it seems like there are no faces (it is just the 1-skeleton) so the boundary map will be a formal sum of the vertices.

Comment: There is a $(-1)^i$ in the definition of $\partial."

Comment: You should really try to give the context of your question. Yes, your counting of the simplices is correct for the second picture, but only after reading what Hatcher intends to do with it, as this alone is not clear from a picture.

Comment: And one 3-simplex.

Comment: @JMP There is no 3-simplex which is exactly why context is missing here - one cannot tell from the picture alone. But reading p. 104 on Hatcher reveals his intention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's related to the [parity of a permuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation).

Changing a vertex and changing the order of vertices by an adjacent transposition both change the sign.

The definition of the boundary operator for simplices is given here:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_homology#Boundaries_and_cycles